# Change Unity's default material for newly created SpriteRenderer objects

Tags: unity-game-engine

By default, Unity adds the `Sprites-Default` material to any new `SpriteRenderer` object / component in the scene.

However after switching to the Universal Render Pipeline (`URP`) and enabling the lighting workflow Unity starts to automatically assign the `Sprite-Lit-Default` to everything instead.

My question is kind of two-fold but bassically ends up as a single answer hopefully:

1. After switching to `Sprite-Lit-Default`, is there a way of switching back to `Sprites-Default` as the default assigned material?
2. Even better, is there a way to set any (eg a custom made material) as the default that Unity uses when a `SpriteRenderer` is newly added to the scene?

Appreciate any help on the subject thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your URP Asset, click on Render Data to open folder:\

[image]

At Default Material Type -> Custom -> Choose your default material type:

[image]

Comment: That's great thank you for the help! Appreciate it :)